# Mobile first Platform 7.1 - Display user agreement when Application is downloaded

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We have requirement to display user agreement when first time user downloads the application. Is there any event or method that is invoked only one time when the application is downloaded. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such "first time only" method provided by the MobileFirst Platform.

What I would suggest for your requirement would to persistently store the acceptance of the user agreement in a JSONStore document.  When you start the app, query the JSONStore to see if it's previously been recorded that the user agreement was accepted, and if not, then present the agreement and don't allow the user to proceed in the app until the agreement is accepted.  Then, of course, once the agreement is accepted, record that fact in a JSONStore document, and start the application's normal flow.

Comment: Thanks. I implemented it the same way you suggested using JSONStore.

Comment: I'm very glad to hear that the information helped you!  If you're satisfied with the answer that was provided, could I ask you to mark my answer as "Accepted" so that your question doesn't continue to show as a question that has no accepted answer?  Thanks!